# How to calculate when scroll is near bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I calculate when scroll is near bottom by this function:

```
$(window).bind( "scroll", function(){ 
    console.log($(window).height());//window heigth
    console.log($(window).scrollTop()); //returns scroll position from top of 
});
```

Do I need something else?

Comment: You need to compare the value to the "near bottom" value instead of printing to the console...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do, no?

```
$(window).bind( "scroll", function(){ 
    var windowHt = $(window).height();
    var myPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (myPos > (windowHt - 100)) { // adjust offset to suit
        do stuff;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see an example when getting to the bottom...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if( ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= $(document).height()-200) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gWD66/2631/

This will alert you when you have 200px or more to the bottom...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. OP doesn't know how to compare the values, just how to output to console. They won't know how to calculate the difference. To answer a question, you should answer it fully not leave gaps. :)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i'll try to improve my answers...i've just updated this answer...